# CMake Error: CMake was unable to find a build program corresponding to "Unix Makefiles". CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM is not set

Tags: c++, cmake

I am doing cross compile on windows 10  x64 with linaro-aarch64-2018.05 to make an enviroment  , c++11
cmake version 3.1.6
when I gen make file with

```
set GENMAKE_DIR=genmake-cv22-win-Linaro-aarch64
set VERSION=cv22-win-Linaro-aarch64
set CROSSMAKETOOL=cs-make-2013.11-33.exe

..\genmake-tools-win32\genMakefiles-win32.bat
```

and 
tool-chain file

```
##--- target system
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Linux)        #--- Name of the OS CMake is building for. (uname -s)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION 4.9.0)     #--- OS version CMake is building for. (uname -r)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR unknown) #--- The name of the CPU CMake is building for. (uname -p)

##--- crosstool path 
set(CROSSTOOL_DIR c:/arm-linux/linaro-aarch64-2018.05)
set(CROSSTOOL_NAME aarch64-linux-gnu)
set(CROSSTOOL_VER 7.1.1)
#set(OS_DIR d:/s2-sdk/ambarella/kernel/linux)

##--- crosstool compiler
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER ${CROSSTOOL_DIR}/bin/${CROSSTOOL_NAME}-gcc.exe)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER ${CROSSTOOL_DIR}/bin/${CROSSTOOL_NAME}-g++.exe)

#--- where is the target environment.
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH ${CROSSTOOL_DIR})

##--- search for programs in the build host directories.
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)
#--- for libraries and headers in the target directories
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRATY ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)
```

everything is fine when I under windows 7 but, when I change to windows 10 
the error showed up
the log:

```
D:\Project\frdatabase\genmake-cv22-win-Linaro-aarch64>copy ..\genmake-tools-win32\make-console.bat     ..\build
copy an file

D:\Project\frdatabase\genmake-cv22-win-Linaro-aarch64>copy ..\genmake-tools-win32\sh.exe
        ..\build\
copy an file

D:\Project\frdatabase\genmake-cv22-win-Linaro-aarch64>copy ..\genmake-tools-win32\cs-make-2013.11-33.exe        ..\build\make.exe
copy an file

D:\Project\frdatabase\genmake-cv22-win-Linaro-aarch64>cd ..\build

D:\Project\frdatabase\build>cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=toolchain-cv22-win-Linaro-aarch64.cmake -G"Unix Makefiles"  ../trunk
CMake Error: CMake was unable to find a build program corresponding to "Unix Makefiles".  CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM is not set.  You probably need to select a different build tool.
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "D:/Project/frdatabase/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".

D:\Project\frdatabase\build>cd ..\genmake-cv22-win-Linaro-aarch64

D:\Project\frdatabase\genmake-cv22-win-Linaro-aarch64>pause
```

CmakeOutput:

```
The target system is: Linux - 4.9.0 - unknown
The host system is: Windows - 10.0.18362 - AMD64
```

there are many similar errors on the internet but all of them they didn'y use the correct make but I am pretty sure I use the right one since I got it from my coworker who is under windows 10 too

Answer (score 0):

the problem is about the version of cmake
3.16.0 has this problem,but it can build under 3.10.3.